# How do I reuse connections with curl_easy?

Tags: curl, tcp, julia, libcurl

I'm writing code with the `curl_easy` interface of libcurl, and am having a hard time
getting it to reuse connections. Details below.

```
curl --version
curl 7.58.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.58.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1 zlib/1.2.11
libidn2/2.0.4 libpsl/0.19.1 (+libidn2/2.0.4) nghttp2/1.30.0 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2018-01-24
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3
pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB
SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy PSL
```

My code runs through a series of unit tests all of which have to connect to
the same host over H2, so I've set up persistent connections. I call
curl_easy_init once, then all the global `curl_easy_setopt` values, then in a
loop, I make the requests by calling `curl_easy_setopt` to set post fields,
url, content length, and then `curl_easy_perform`.
I only call `curl_easy_cleanup` after all requests have been made.
I have the following options set:

```
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 1
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2
CURLOPT_SSLVERSION 7<<16
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION = 4
CURLOPT_TCP_FASTOPEN = 1
CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE = 1
CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING = ""
CURLOPT_TRANSFER_ENCODING = 1
CURLOPT_POST = 1
CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT = 0
CURLOPT_VERBOSE = 1
CURLOPT_SSLCERT
CURLOPT_SSLKEY
CURLOPT_CAINFO
```

Verbose output looks like this:

```
* TCP_NODELAY set
* TCP_FASTOPEN_CONNECT set
* Connected to XYZ () port 443 (#0)
* found 3 certificates in /data/certs/ca_chain.pem
* found 401 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* server certificate verification OK
* server certificate status verification SKIPPED
* error fetching CN from cert:The requested data were not available.
* common name: (matched)
* server certificate expiration date OK
* server certificate activation date OK
* certificate public key: RSA
* certificate version: #3
* subject:
* start date: Mon, 13 Jul 2020 08:04:30 GMT
* expire date: Mon, 20 Jul 2020 08:05:00 GMT
* issuer: C=US,ST=MA,L=Cambridge,O=XXXXX,CN=YYYYY
* compression: NULL
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade:
len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x9036570)
> POST /foo/ HTTP/2

<Request>

* We are completely uploaded and fine
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!

<Response>

* Connection #0 to host XYZ left intact
```

```
* Found bundle for host XYZ: 0xe141520 [can multiplex]
* Connection #0 is still name resolving, can't reuse
* Trying IP...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* TCP_FASTOPEN_CONNECT set
* Connected to XYZ () port 443 (#1)
* found 3 certificates in /data/certs/ca_chain.pem
* found 401 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL re-using session ID
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* server certificate verification OK
* server certificate status verification SKIPPED
* error fetching CN from cert:The requested data were not available.
* common name: (matched)
* server certificate expiration date OK
* server certificate activation date OK
* certificate public key: RSA
* certificate version: #3
* subject:
* start date: Mon, 13 Jul 2020 08:04:30 GMT
* expire date: Mon, 20 Jul 2020 08:05:00 GMT
* issuer: C=US,ST=MA,L=Cambridge,O=XXXXX,CN=YYYYY
* compression: NULL
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade:
len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x9036570)

<Request>

* We are completely uploaded and fine
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
< HTTP/2 200
< vary: accept-encoding
< content-encoding: gzip
< content-type: text/plain
< date: Mon, 13 Jul 2020 19:30:36 GMT
< server: abcdefg

<Response>

* Connection #1 to host XYZ left intact
```

```
* Found bundle for host XYZ: 0xe141520 [can multiplex]
* Connection #0 is still name resolving, can't reuse
* Connection #1 is still name resolving, can't reuse
```

And so on...

It fairly soon gets to this:

```
* Connection cache is full, closing the oldest one.
* Closing connection 0
* Connection #5 to host XYZ left intact
```

This closing of the oldest connection continues from here on in until
either everything is done, or a TLS handshake error puts the connection
into an inconsistent state.

Any idea what I can do to get curl to reuse the H2 connection to the host?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Not exactly an [mcve]  , but I does seem like a difficult problem. It might help if you add a tag for the programming language you are using, it will definitely increase the number of readers for your Q. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter thanks, I ended up trimming my code to a point where I found the problem. It's with `TCP_FASTOPEN`. If I take that out, connections are reused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with `CURLOPT_TCP_FASTOPEN`. Turning off that option will allow connection reuse. FAST_OPEN is only needed if using multiple TCP connections to avoid a roundtrip during handshake.

Traditional TCP handshake is a 3-way protocol.

- The initiator sends a SYN packet to the peer,
- The peer responds with a SYN-ACK packet to the initiator,
- Finally the initiator sends its own ACK.

After sending the ACK, the initiator sends the first data packet. In all, 4 packets to send data.

With FAST_OPEN, data transfer (on connections after the first connection) can begin from the first packet. It uses a TCP Cookie (TFO) to establish that the two hosts have recently successfully connected to each other.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_Fast_Open for more information.

Comment: Can you please link/give more details about what is "roundtrip during handshake" and its consequent negative effects? thanks.

Comment: I've added more details to the comment @T.Todua